# How can I use multiple roots depending on the type of user in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I currently want to redirect to a different root page based on the type of user that is accessing the application.  I can tell the type of user based on preferences that are set in their sign up settings.  In this case, there are three types of users: operator, builder, writer.

I currently have it set up where it is

```
root 'operator#index', as: :operator_root
root 'builder#index', as: :builder_root
root 'writer#index', as: :writer_root
```

In my application controller, I created a passthrough method as I saw on a different question (can't seem to find it again).

```
def passthrough
  path = get_root_path
  redirect_to path
end

def get_root_path
  if current_user.operator
    return operator_root_path
  elsif current_user.builder
    return builder_root_path
  else
    return writer_root_path
  end
end
```

How can I make this work for my situation?  It works for the operator_root, but the others get a redirect loop.

Comment: Where you call passthrough?

Comment: oh i have a root 'application#passthrough'

Answer (score 1):

root is a special syntax to define the controller#action to send a user that visits '/'.  You should only have one root defined.

In your case, I believe you really want something like:

```
get 'operator', to: 'operator#index', as: :operator_root
get 'builder', to: 'builder#index', as: :builder_root
get 'writer', to: 'writer#index', as: :writer_root
```

However, that will result in each user ending up at a different url (e.g. - /operator, /builder or /writer).

Alternatively, you could define your root url to go through one controller such as:

```
root 'main#index'
```

And then within the MainController#index method you can modify the view you show based on the current_user that is logged in such as:

```
if current_user.operator?
  render :operator_root
elsif current_user.writer?
  render :writer_root
else current_user.builder?
  render :builder_root
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on TomDavies post, I was able to come up with a solution.

In my routes.rb, I set the application root for inside the subdomain, and then defined two get routes.

```
root 'application#index', as: :subdomain_root
get 'operator', to: 'operator#index', as: :operator_root
get 'writer', to: 'writer#index', as: :writer_root
get 'builder', to: 'builder#index', as: :builder_root
```

In my `ApplicationController`, i then had the following function for application#index

```
def index
  if current_user.builder
    render 'builder/index'
  elsif current_user.writer
    render 'writer/index'
  else
    render 'operator/index'
  end
end
```